# Including multiple folder to make standalone executable with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller, executable

I'm trying to make a standalone executable from my python project, but I'm unable to make it work. Below is complete detail....

My project structure look something like this ( in project root dir )

```
csab:
  2022:
    round1:
      some_files.csv
tool.py
```

Since I wanted to create standalone executable form it, and ofcrs i need those csv files as its contain data which is required by my program so i used `pyinstaller` for this purpose.

On windows i tried following command.

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --add-data "E:/python/jee_counsellor/csab;csab/" --add-data "E:/python/jee_counsellor/josaa;josaa/"  "E:/python/jee_counsellor/tool.py"
```

And on linux, i tried with this

```
python -m PyInstaller --onefile --add-data 'csab/*:csab' --add-data 'josaa/*:josaa' --exclude-module _tkinter tool.py
```

But none of them seems to work as it cant find my csv paths correctly.
Here is the error details ( same on both linux and windows )

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tool.py", line 250, in <module>
  File "tool.py", line 16, in pre_setup
  File "tool.py", line 36, in csab_rounds
  File "tool.py", line 54, in csv_files
  File "pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 912, in read_csv
  File "pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 577, in _read
  File "pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1407, in __init__
  File "pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1661, in _make_engine
  File "pandas\io\common.py", line 859, in get_handle
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:\\python\\jee_counsellor\\output\\csab\\2022\\round_2\\ranks.csv'
[19596] Failed to execute script 'tool' due to unhandled exception!
```

Snippet from my code where it fails.

```
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        csab_rounds = round
        csv_path = os.path.join(cwd, "csab", "2022", f"round_{csab_rounds}", "ranks.csv")
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```

Do I need to update my code or any other workaround for this with pyinstaller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build command has a slight mistake.
On `Linux`, it should be

`python -m PyInstaller --onefile --add-data 'csab:csab' --add-data 'josaa:josaa' --exclude-module _tkinter tool.py`.

Notice the `--add-data 'josaa:josaa'`.

From the documentation,

1. The first string (`josaa` here) specifies the file or files as they are in this system now.
2. The second string (again `josaa` here) specifies the name of the folder to contain the files at run-time.

You do not need to write `/*`, the entire content of the folder will be automatically included.

Link to documentation: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-add-data

Recommended way would be to use a `spec` file.

https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files

Comment: What about windows ?

Comment: `--add-data "josaa;josaa"` should work IMO.